# Canvas / precise line drawing

Tags: javascript

I'm playing currently with javascript and canvas around.

I want draw a 1 pixel border without blurry lines.
I've read about the 0.5 px translation.

```
var shift = 0.5;
if (x1 === x2) {
  var shiftX = shift;
  var shiftY = 0;
} else {
  var shiftX = 0;
  var shiftY = shift;
}
```

What is wrong ? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/astropanic/xaxK4/)

Why is one pixel missing in the right bottom corner ?

Comment: Use `var shift = -.5;`

Comment: Not sure the reason, but this fixes `ctx.line(400, 1, 400, 401);`  One pixel longer.

Comment: @ZachSaucier, than you lose the top left part... http://jsfiddle.net/astropanic/xaxK4/2/

Comment: @gongzhitaao - ugly hack, that's why I asked for the reason, I want understand the cause, but thanks.

Comment: Try removing the css styles that give the canvas its width and height. After considerable experience with html canvas graphics I notice that the canvas gets REALLY SAD if you css-style its width/height - always use the inline attributes instead.

Comment: @GershomMaes - it didn't helped http://jsfiddle.net/astropanic/xaxK4/4/

Answer (score 2):

This works!!

```
ctx.line = function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var shift = 0.5;

    if (x1 === x2) {
        var shiftX = x1 < 2 ? shift : -shift;
        var shiftY = 0;
    } else if (y1 === y2) {
        var shiftX = 0;
        var shiftY = y1 < 2 ? shift : -shift;
    } else {
        var shiftX = 0;
        var shiftY = 0;
    }

    ctx.translate(shiftX, shiftY);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.translate(-shiftX, -shiftY);
};
```

The issue with your attempt was that a pixel too close to the edge could be shifted "off" the canvas. This method ensures that if the point is within 2 pixels of an edge, the shifting occurs in a direction AWAY from the edge.

Comment: Don't change the shift value - It's not meant to be changed!

Comment: the shift depends on the line width: var shift = (lineWidth % 2) / 2;

Comment: I admittedly was not taking the lineWidth into account when I coded this. I'll give this answer a quick edit.

Comment: The shift does not depend on the lineWidth. taking a sift of floor(lineWidth / 2) will just right / bottom center it. Imagine the grid of pixels : only the 0.5 shift matters, and a, say 3.5 shift will draw just the same as with a 0.5 pixels, just 3 pixels below.

Answer (score 0):

The center of a screen pixel is it at its (+0.5,+0.5) context2d coordinate.

Truth is you don't have to translate by 0.5 for x OR y, but for *both*, be it a vertical or horizontal line.

Your whole code is equivalent to this one :

```
ctx.sline(0    , 0.5,      399,   0.5);
ctx.sline(399.5 ,0,        399.5, 399);
ctx.sline(0     ,399.5,    399,   399.5);
ctx.sline(0.5   ,399,      0.5,   0);
// With 'sline' a straight line function that just use provided coordinates.
```

It's easy to see that points do not connect one to another. There are 8 points involved here, not 4.
The right-down most point (399.5, 399.5) is never reached, while other corners have at least 2 points drawn.

A simple way to settle the issue once and for all is to translate the canvas by (0.5, 0.5) on context creation, and use rounded coordinates after that.
Obviously -as it should always be done- save/restore the context when using a transform.

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/xaxK4/6/

```
ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#AAAAAA";

ctx.line = function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    x1 = 0 | x1 ;
    y1 = 0 | y1 ;
    x2 = 0 | x2 ;
    y2 = 0 | y2 ;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.stroke();
};

ctx.line(1, 1, 399, 1);
ctx.line(399, 1, 399, 399);
ctx.line(399, 399, 1, 399);
ctx.line(1, 399, 1, 1);
```

And do not use css width/height, or maybe set it in the code to ensure you never have canvas.width != canvas.style.width or canvas.height != canvas.style.height, unless you know what you're doing in having different values of course. But if you don't plan on playing with resolution, to support hiDpi devices, or to render at a lower resolution, quit using css sizing.